# Vannila JS - how can I pause a YT video on modal exit

Tags: javascript

Ok, I managed to add a video inside a modal, but now I'm a little lost, because I can't pause the video when I leave the modal.

I tryed a lot of things and searched a lot here too, but I only find jQuery solutions and I'm looking for a vanilla solution...

my js code:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YouTube Iframe player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=pt-PT) to handle the video (iframe), and after the `player` is [initialized](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=pt-PT#Loading_a_Video_Player) you can simple do:

```
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    player.pauseVideo();
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        player.pauseVideo();
    } 
}
```